# What is wrong with this batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a batch that reads a number from a file, increments it and saves it back into this file... This is what I came up with:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST script\BUILDVERSION (
  SET /p input = <script\BUILDVERSION
  SET /a result=%input%+1
  ECHO %result% > script\BUILDVERSION
) ELSE (
  ECHO 0 > script\BUILDVERSION
)
```

At first it worked in a strange way, the result from reading the number from the file seemed to be a small random number, the result of the sum seemed random too... I don't know what I did, but now it doesn't even read the number from file into the variable...

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: The problem with *any* batch scripts is that they *are batch scripts*. =)

Comment: Well, I agree and I would never waste my time with it for fun, but I need this for an ant build script to work under windows (the bash counterpart for Linux took me 5 minutes to implement with no bash scripting experience)

Comment: Is it possible to use vbscript?  It's less worse than batch scripting.

Comment: sure, I wasn't questioning your question, it was just a tongue-in-cheek remark about the joys of writing batch scripts. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `%input%` and `%result%`, try using `!input!` and `!result!`.  This seems to work better when using delayed expansion.  Also, make sure you don't have any unnecessary spaces when reading from the file.  You'll end up with:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST script\BUILDVERSION (
  SET /p input=<script\BUILDVERSION
  SET /a result=!input!+1
  ECHO !result! > script\BUILDVERSION
) ELSE (
  ECHO 0 > script\BUILDVERSION
)
```

Comment: In arithmetic assignments variables can be referenced simply by their names, without `!`s or `%`s. So `!input!` can be replaced with `input`.